# When I format two different times they both come out as the same time, is there a way to fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

When formatting 2 different times, both come out as the same time. I'm using h:mm:ss a

```
   correctTime(time) {
    var convertedTime = moment().format("h:mm:ss", time);
    return convertedTime;
  }
```

The 2 times that go in:

- 2019-10-03T11:00:00
- 2019-10-03T11:20:00

The 2 times that come out:

- 1:13:55
- 1:13:55

What I want to get out:

- 11:00:00
- 11:20:00

Is there anything that I'm just not doing right?

Comment: You should use moment like this: `moment("2019-10-03T11:00:00").format("hh:mm:ss"),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing this:

```
moment().format("h:mm:ss", time)
```

you are formatting the current time.

What you want to do is to format your variable 'time'.

If your variable 'time' is already a moment, just call time.format("h:mm:ss"), if it is a javascript date, convert it to moment and then call the format method.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `moment()` constructor, it creates a moment instance representing the current time. So instead use [parsing](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) to create an instance with the time you are providing.

Then format that instance as using format method providing the date format as the first and only parameter.

```js
var formatted = moment('2019-10-03T11:20:09').format("h:mm:ss");
console.log(formatted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`moment()` returns current date time.

so when you format on current date it returns the current date of local timezone.

`moment(time).format("hh:mm:ss")` this is the correct format.